# What is the best way to automate creating SQL .bak or .bacpac backup files and saving them to an Azure cloud storage container?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

Currently I am tasked with researching a solution to easily copying data from one environment to another (QA to DEV for example) as well as having the flexibility of going to different times to compare our data. It is an easy task to do locally with SSMS and I am looking for the best ways to do it using Azure and it's tools.

These are the options that I found so far:

- Backup Service and Backup Vault (The MS solution that I am not asking for. They don't generate `.bak` files)
- Azure Function to execute generate and transfer SQL (flexible but the code needs to be maintained + manage authentication)
- Powershell process with Azure Automate (Flexible too but needs to be maintained)
- Datafactory/SSIS (Still learning and researching)

Anyone got any tools/methods that are worth looking into before I dive deeper with a solution?

Comment: You may use [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure) to sync databases between environments. It will not create `bak` or `bacpac` file, but it provides you synchronization with minimal effort.

Comment: Hi @Ammar, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure SQL database, [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure) is one of feature for the data sync between Azure SQL and SQL server(on-premise). Some [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database#sync-req-lim) are that Azure SQL database must be hub and each must have a primary key.  That may not suit you.

Per my experience, Data Factory is the best one for you. You can copy the data between different environment, in Sink settings, we can using upsert(insert or update) operation to sync the data.

If you only want to schedule the backup automatically for the SQL, the third-part tool also could feed your request: [SQL Backup and FTP](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/).

Since you have searched a lot and found almost all the options in Azure, all the ways can  achieve that. You need to know your real request, data sync or auto backup create the .bacpac file to storage. That's not a good question to help you find the best way. The way you like, the way is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I went with writing an Azure Automate powershell script. including cmdlts like  New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport and passing in the parameters was ticky but it finally did the job.